# MYSQL : IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table called `jdwf_orders_main` if the value of `jaj_jno` is present in `jdwf_alien_jobs` table.

I am trying to do it using `IF EXISTS` but I can't seem to get the syntax right.
What is wrong with my syntax.

```
IF ( EXISTS (SELECT * from jdwf_alien_jobs where jaj_jno = '7200000') ,
UPDATE jdwf_orders_main set jom_adv_name = 'IAM OP' where jom_job_no = '7200000',
UPDATE jdwf_orders_main set jom_adv_name = 'IAM Noob' where jom_job_no = '7200000');
```

Comment: why update same record with two time? it overwrite first one

Comment: @BhargavChudasama the OP tries to run two different `UPDATE` queries on the two branches of an `IF()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support the operation you tried. It provides another way to get the same result: update two or more joined tables in a single `UPDATE` query.

I cannot test but somethings like this should work:

```
UPDATE jdwf_orders_main om
    LEFT JOIN from jdwf_alien_jobs aj ON om.jom_job_no = aj.jaj_jno
SET om.jom_adv_name = IF(af.jaj_no IS NULL, 'IAM Noob', 'IAM OP')
WHERE om.jom_job_no = '7200000'
```

#### How it works

It joins the table `jdwf_orders_main` (aliased as `om`) with `jdwf_alien_jobs` (aliased as `aj`) on the `om.jom_job_no = aj.jaj_jno` condition.
The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from the left table (`om`) appear in the result set; if a row does not have a matching row in the right table, a row full of `NULL`s is used for the fields of the right table.
The `WHERE` clause filters only the rows that match the condition `om.jom_job_no = '7200000'` to be modified by the `UPDATE` statement.
The `SET` clause updates `om.jom_adv_name` (i.e. the column `jom_adv_name` from the `jdwf_orders_main` table) with the value computed by the `IF()` function.
The `IF()` function returns `'IAM Noob'` if `af.jaj_jno` is `NULL`. This happens when for the row from `om` does not exist any matching row in `af` (see the explanation of the `LEFT JOIN` clause above). Otherwise (when a matching row exists), `af.jaj_jno` is not `NULL` and the `IF()` function returns `'IAM OP'`.

Comment: much appreciated. This workaround works too. Thanks.